# PulsarClientException: Connection already closed - verified network, firewall, Pulsar token and role are correct

Tags: java, spring, apache-pulsar

I'm using a Java Spring consumer for Apache Pulsar, and my app won't start.

We've verified the following:

- the Pulsar token is correct. (We're using Pulsar token auth.)
- we can hit our target SSL Pulsar port (6651) using telnet and curl commands, so it's not a firewall or network issue
- the role has adequate permission in Pulsar
- we're hitting the correct endpoint for the right Pulsar cluster
- we're using the correct trust cert in our client for this environment

We can also reproduce the issue from another environment with this client code:

```
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClient;
PulsarClient client = PulsarClient.builder()
                .serviceUrl("pulsar+ssl://pulsarUrl:6651/")
                .tlsTrustCertsFilePath("path/to/ca.cert.pem")
                .enableTlsHostnameVerification(true)
                .allowTlsInsecureConnection(false)
                .authentication(AuthenticationFactory.token("yourTokenHere"))
                .build();
```

We're seeing this exception in our logs:

> Unable to initialize Pulsar consumer:
> org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException: Connection already
> closed

The more detailed log is here:

> Jul 26, 2021 10:00:19 -0600 [15277 1] com.newrelic INFO: Using default
> collector host: collector.newrelic.com
> {"@timestamp":"2021-07-26T16:01:31.184Z", "log.level":"ERROR",
> "message":"Application run failed", "ecs.version":
> "1.2.0","service.name":"ProductExampleWoker","event.dataset":"AppExampleWoker.log","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","log.origin":{"file.name":"SpringApplication.java","function":"reportFailure","file.line":826},"error.type":"org.springframework.beans.factory.eanCreationException","error.message":"Error
> creating bean with name 'consumer' defined in class path resource
> [com/myCompany/Example/ppw/service/config/ServiceConfig.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.apache.pulsar.client.api.Consumer]: Factory method
> 'consumer' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException: Connection already
> closed","error.stack_trace":[
> "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'consumer' defined in class path resource
> [com/overstock/Example/ppw/service/config/ServiceConfig.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.apache.pulsar.client.api.Consumer]: Factory method
> 'consumer' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException: Connection already
> closed",

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Connection already closed

This means the connection is getting dropped after it connects but before it completes the handshake.

In this case, the Pulsar cluster is configured in a way that requires hostname verification to be disabled.
Please set `.enableTlsHostnameVerification(false)` in your Pulsar consumer client.

Another thing that can cause this is if the token has an extra space character or is formatted incorrectly (such as if it's missing a character at the end.)

If you run the lookup command on the topic you're trying to connect to, you can tail the log of that broker and watch for an exception like this to show up when you restart the consumer:

> javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Failed to authentication token:
> Unable to verify RSA signature using configured PublicKey. Signature
> length not correct: got 255 but was expecting 256
> at org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.AuthenticationProviderToken.parseToken(AuthenticationProviderToken.java:116)
> ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-broker-common-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
> at org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.AuthenticationProviderToken.authenticate(AuthenticationProviderToken.java:76)
> ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-broker-common-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
> at org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.OneStageAuthenticationState.(OneStageAuthenticationState.java:46)
> ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-broker-common-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
> at org.apache.pulsar.broker.authentication.AuthenticationProvider.newAuthState(AuthenticationProvider.java:76)
> ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-broker-common-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
> at org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.ServerCnx.handleConnect(ServerCnx.java:548)
> [org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-broker-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
> at org.apache.pulsar.common.api.PulsarDecoder.channelRead(PulsarDecoder.java:148)
> [org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-common-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
> at  . . .

Not every auth failure will show up that way, but if you see that exception, then you will know for sure what the problem is.

If the topic doesn't exist because you need to pause an upstream consumer, you can create the subscription manually in order to find out which broker the topic lives in so you know which broker log to follow while troubleshooting.